# replace substring in matching string

Tags: sed

I need to replace `value` with `new_value` in strings

```
key:value
key: value
key:  value
```

To get

```
key:new_value
key: new_value
key:  new_value
```

Number of spaces after `:` is arbitrary. The regex to match would be `key: *value`.
How do I replace `value` with `new_value` in such strings preserving number of spaces with sed?

To clarify, `key1:value` or `key:value1` do not match due to different key/value, so such strings are not altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `sed` to match all cases:

```
sed -E 's/^([[:blank:]]*key[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*)value([[:blank:]]|$)/\1new_value/' file
```

```
key:new_value
key: new_value
key:  new_value
```

This allows 0 or more whitespaces at:

- before `key` at start
- between `key` and `:`
- between `:` and value
- after `value` before end
- `[[:blank:]]` matches a space or a tab

Comment: No need in `g` at the end:
`sed -E '.../g'` ?

Comment: But I don't have `/g` at the end

Comment: Not my downvote. Good answer.
I was asking if 'g' is needed in the end to process all matches, as it is usually done.

Comment: @user2052436 `g` is for when you need to process multiple matches on a line. Per the sample input in your question you don't have any cases where there are multiple matches on a line and so specifying `g` wouldn't make sense. If that's wrong then, of course, fix the example in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
sed 's/^\(key: *\)value/\1new_vale/' file
```

Comment: No need in `g` at the end: `sed '.../g'` ?

Comment: No, trailing `g` not required here.  To understand what `g` does, try out the following two commands:

```foo="aaaa";
echo $foo | sed 's/a/X';
echo $foo | sed 's/a/X/g'
```